# ntfs file manager mount options

Tags: mount, ntfs, dolphin

I'm using Dolphin to mount my NTFS partitions. Everything used to work fine, but for some time the partitions have been getting mounted with both rw and ro options, which results in them being mounted as ro, instead of rw. Is there a way to modify those mount options?

Comment: Please check log output, probably Windows has been hibernated instead of shut down,

Comment: Windows was shut down properly.

Comment: Windows version? If 8 or newer the default is a semi-hibernated state named fast startup. If you have disabled this in Windows before, an update may have reseted it to the default.

Comment: Windows 10. But how can it affect partition mounting? Especially when I'm mounting 2 partitions, with Windows being only on one of them.